# CSS z-index does not take effect

Tags: css

I expect with the following code 'max-button' be visible but it hides behind the grid. What is wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Grid</title>
<style>
#sketch {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: transparent url(grid.gif) repeat scroll 0 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
#max-button {
    z-index: 9999;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sketch"></div>
<div id="max-button"><img src="maximize.gif"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here are the two images:

maximize.gif: [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8c213c4a8a.gif](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8c213c4a8a.gif)
grid.gif: [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/af716eaf7d.gif](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/af716eaf7d.gif)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#maxbutton` needs to be absolutely positioned as well.

Explanation:  the grid is taken out of the default document flow, hence the button is ending up underneath where the grid would have taken it. Absolute positioning enables z-index.